# Passing variables to curl command in child_process.exec fails

Tags: node.js, curl, exec

I was trying to use `child_process.exec` to call curl with a long command in order to send some data to an API. Something similar to the following example:

```
exec('git log --oneline | wc -l', function(error, stdin, stderr) { 
  if (stdin > 1) {
      exec('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d \'{"value1": "\'"$arg"\'"}\' https://https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/<my-key>', { "env" : {"arg": stdin } });
  }
})
```

So if a git repo includes more than one line in its `git log` output, then  you execute a POST request to some API (here, a simple webhook in ifttt.com), in which you're passing some variable (`arg`) in the process.

Notice that this is the best attempt, but in general, I was struggling quite a bit to escape single and double quotes. In this particular case, the HTTP request was not sent correctly because the body includes a line break:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: <some-host>
User-Agent: curl/7.50.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 16

{"value1": "2
"}
```

At the end, I had to use an external bash script:

```
exec('./send_request.sh $arg', { "env": {"arg": stdin } });
```

but I'm still very curious on how to make it work within the same `js` file.

If it helps, I'm running node 6.11.0 and curl 7.52.1.

Comment: You can use `spawn` instead `exec`. `spawn` accepts args as array, so string concatenation is not necessary.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, that sounds like a better way to do it. Can you post an example on how to use it?

Comment: I was able to make it work. Yes, that is also a good improvement: `spawn('curl', ['-H "Content-Type: application/json"', '-X POST', '-d \"{"value1": "\'"$arg"\'"}\"', <url>], ...` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
exec('git log --oneline | wc -l', function(error, stdin, stderr) { 
  if (stdin > 1) {
      exec('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d \'{"value1": "\'"$arg"\'"}\' https://https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/<my-key>', { "env" : {"arg": stdin.replace(/\n/g, '') } });
  }
})
```

What is happening is that your variable 'stdin' (you should rename it to **'stdout'**) has a `\n` at the end of it.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, that works... but I was trying to figure out a simpler way to call such commands without struggling so much with escaping characters.

Comment: @RobertSmith I added an explanation to the answer. You should rename the parameter `stdin` to `stdout`, as it really is the `stdout` from the executed command. Out of curiosity, why are you using `curl`instead of do the `POST` from Node.js itself?

Comment: You're correct, it should be `stdout`. Excellent question... I think I initially was using curl when testing the webhook, but I suppose a POST request from node should be a better alternative.

Comment: For sure, your life will get easier. Go with https://www.npmjs.com/package/request or https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Thanks. An additional question: When you need to call a long command in the shell, would you use spawn as suggested by Aikon or something else? As I said, the first concern here is dealing with escaping characters.

Comment: You would have the same escaping issues by using `spawn`. The main difference between both, is that `spawn` fits better to handle large volumes of data coming via `stdout`, as it will return a streaming interface from the executed command. With `exec` you can end up stumbling upon its buffer limit.

Comment: Oh, okay. But then is there a better way?

Comment: For this case, follow my suggestion of doing that directly from the main process, using one of the packages that I mentioned before, without relying on `child_process`. Take a look at the docs, and search for **.post**. I guarantee you that will be really easy.

Comment: Indeed. I was just wondering about other cases. Maybe it would be better to outsource all the heavy lifting to a bash script if a lot of shell executions are needed.